# HTML5 Canvas lags

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I recently added a canvas element,random dots on sphere,in my page.It works great on PC but on mobile phones and tablets rendering is very slow.
How can I speed up the sphere and reduce lags?
Any help would be much appreciated.[GitHub example](https://yovchenko.github.io/sphere/)

Comment: It seems you are quite simply pushing the boundary of your mobile device. To increase the speed you must either optimize your code or degrade your graphics somewhat. You could optimize by for instance registering if an `update` requires a `render`, possibly saving ressources if nothing has moved. You could also half the resolution of your canvas, exponentially reducing the amount of pixels to calculate. (you scale the canvas with css afterwards, although that might blur it)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try to play with "update" and "render".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much room for improvements.

In the render loop you have

```
    for (var p of points) {
        p = rotation.multiplyVector(p);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x + c.width / 2, p.y + c.height / 2, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

The beginPath is not needed if you are rendering the same style over and over

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var p of points) {
        p = rotation.multiplyVector(p);
        const x = p.x + c.width / 2;
        const y = p.y + c.height / 2;
        ctx.moveTo(x + 2, y)
        ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }
    ctx.fill();
```

Then the matrix vector multiply has needless vetting and needless memory assignment and object instantiations

You had

```
Matrix3.prototype.multiplyVector = function (vec) {
    if (vec instanceof Vector3) {
        var x = this.data[0 + 0 * 3] * vec.x + this.data[0 + 1 * 3] * vec.y + this.data[0 + 2 * 3] * vec.z;
        var y = this.data[1 + 0 * 3] * vec.x + this.data[1 + 1 * 3] * vec.y + this.data[1 + 2 * 3] * vec.z;
        var z = this.data[2 + 0 * 3] * vec.x + this.data[2 + 1 * 3] * vec.y + this.data[2 + 2 * 3] * vec.z;

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Will this ever not happen `if (vec instanceof Vector3) {` ??? not in your code so why waste the CPU time doing it.

Then `this.data[2 + 0 * 3]` The optimiser may get this for you, but mobiles do not optimise as well as desktops and I am not sure if this will be picked up on. Also some browsers are slower when using indirect references  `this.data[?]` is slower than `data[?]`

And creating a new vector with for each circle to immediately discard it is not at all memory friendly. You only need one object so pass it to the function to set.

Improved

```
Matrix3.prototype.multiplyVector = function (vec, retVec = new Vector3(0,0,0)) {
    const d = this.data;
    retVec.x = d[0] * vec.x + d[3] * vec.y + d[6] * vec.z;
    retVec.y = d[1] * vec.x + d[4] * vec.y + d[7] * vec.z;
    retVec.z = d[2] * vec.x + d[5] * vec.y + d[8] * vec.z;
    return retVec;
};
```

Then in the loop

```
const rp = new Vector3(0,0,0);
ctx.beginPath();
for (var p of points) {
    rotation.multiplyVector(p,rp);
    const x = rp.x + c.width / 2;
    const y = rp.y + c.height / 2;
    ctx.moveTo(x + 2, y)
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
ctx.fill();
```

Both the `Vector3` and `Matrix3` objects are very memory wasteful which means CPU cycles you have no control over being used just to assign and delete when you should be reusing memory as shown above.

You have the Matrix rotate function to build the rotation that creates a new matrix to create a rotation matrix which then needs a new matrix to multiply. You create 6 full matrix objects just to get one matrix.

The rotate function is called with 2 of x,y,z as 0 meaning that many of the multiplications and additions are just getting zero or you end up adding omc + cos which equals 1 or you multiply by 1 making no change.

You have

```
Matrix3.rotate = function (angle, x, y, z) {
    var result = new Matrix3();
    result.setIdentity();

    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var omc = 1 - cos;

    result.data[0 + 0 * 3] = x * omc + cos;
    result.data[1 + 0 * 3] = y * x * omc + z * sin;
    result.data[2 + 0 * 3] = x * z * omc - y * sin;

    result.data[0 + 1 * 3] = x * y * omc - z * sin;
    result.data[1 + 1 * 3] = y * omc + cos;
    result.data[2 + 1 * 3] = y * z * omc + x * sin;

    result.data[0 + 2 * 3] = x * z * omc + y * sin;
    result.data[1 + 2 * 3] = y * z * omc - x * sin;
    result.data[2 + 2 * 3] = z * omc + cos;

    return result;
}
```

Create a rotation matrix by directly multiplying a matrix, you will need one for each axis.

```
Matrix3.prototype.rotateX = function(angle, result = new Matrix3()) {
    const r = result.data;
    const d = this.data;
    const c = Math.cos(angle);
    const s = Math.sin(angle));
    const ns = -s;
    r[0] = d[0]
    r[1] = d[1] * c + d[2] * ns;
    r[2] = d[1] * s + d[2] * c;
    r[3] = d[3];
    r[4] = d[4] * c + d[5] * ns;
    r[5] = d[4] * s + d[5] * c;
    r[6] = d[6];
    r[7] = d[7] * c + d[8] * ns;
    r[8] = d[7] * s + d[8] * c;     
    return result;
},
```

Do same for rotateY,rotateZ (each is different than above)

Instance matrix directly setting the identity rather than needing a second call.

```
function Matrix3() { this.data = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] }
```

Set identity with

```
Matrix3.prototype.setIdentity = function () { 
    const d = this.data;
    d.fill(0);
    d[8] = d[4] = d[0] = 1;
}
```

Then in your loop function have access to two matrix objects.

```
const mat1 = new Matrix3();
const mat2 = new Matrix3();
const rp = new Vector3(0,0,0);
const MPI2 = 2 * Math.PI;
function loop(){
    mat1.setIdentity();
    mat1.rotateX(angle.x,mat2);
    mat2.rotateY(angle.y,mat1);
    mat1.rotateZ(angle.z,mat2);
    // your text rendering in here
    const cw = c.width / 2;
    const ch = c.height / 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var p of points) {
        mat2.multiplyVector(p,rp);
        const x = rp.x + cw;
        const y = rp.y + ch;
        ctx.moveTo(x + 2, y)
        ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, MPI2);
    }
    ctx.fill();
}
```

That will give you a little extra speed. Any other improvements will be browser / device specific.

**UPDATE** as requested in the comments the following snippet contains the shortened rotation matrix multiplication of rotation around the X,Y, andZ axis

```js
// How I find the optimum matrix multiplication via 
// eleminating a[?] * 0 = 0 
// reducing  a[?] * 1 = a[?]
//
// The following are the rotations for X,Y,Z as matrix
//-------------------
// rotate X
//  1       0     0
//  0  cos(r) sin(r)
//  0 -sin(r) cos(r)
//-------------------
// rotate Y
//  cos(r) 0 sin(r)
//  0      1      0 
// -sin(r) 0 cos(r)
//-------------------
// rotate Z
//  cos(r) sin(r) 0
// -sin(r) cos(r) 0 
//       0      0 1
// The matrix indexes 
// [0][1][2]
// [3][4][5]
// [6][7][8]
// Using the indexs and multiply is c = a * b
// c[0] = a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[3] + a[2] * b[6]
// c[1] = a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[4] + a[2] * b[7]
// c[2] = a[0] * b[2] + a[1] * b[5] + a[2] * b[8]
// c[3] = a[3] * b[0] + a[4] * b[3] + a[5] * b[6]
// c[4] = a[3] * b[1] + a[4] * b[4] + a[5] * b[7]
// c[5] = a[3] * b[2] + a[4] * b[5] + a[5] * b[8]
// c[6] = a[6] * b[0] + a[7] * b[3] + a[8] * b[6]
// c[7] = a[6] * b[1] + a[7] * b[4] + a[8] * b[7]
// c[8] = a[6] * b[2] + a[7] * b[5] + a[8] * b[8]
// Then use the rotations matrix to find the zeros and ones 
// EG rotate X b[1],b[2],b[3],b[6] are zero and b[0] is one
// c[0] = a[0] * 1    + a[1] * 0    + a[2] * 0   
// c[1] = a[0] * 0    + a[1] * b[4] + a[2] * b[7]
// c[2] = a[0] * 0    + a[1] * b[5] + a[2] * b[8]
// c[3] = a[3] * 1    + a[4] * 0    + a[5] * 0   
// c[4] = a[3] * 0    + a[4] * b[4] + a[5] * b[7]
// c[5] = a[3] * 0    + a[4] * b[5] + a[5] * b[8]
// c[6] = a[6] * 1    + a[7] * 0    + a[8] * 0   
// c[7] = a[6] * 0    + a[7] * b[4] + a[8] * b[7]
// c[8] = a[6] * 0    + a[7] * b[5] + a[8] * b[8]
// then eliminate all the zero terms a[?] * 0 == 0 and 
// remove the 1 from 1 * a[?] = a[?]
// c[0] = a[0] 
// c[1] = a[1] * b[4] + a[2] * b[7]
// c[2] = a[1] * b[5] + a[2] * b[8]
// c[3] = a[3]   
// c[4] = a[4] * b[4] + a[5] * b[7]
// c[5] = a[4] * b[5] + a[5] * b[8]
// c[6] = a[6] 
// c[7] = a[7] * b[4] + a[8] * b[7]
// c[8] = a[7] * b[5] + a[8] * b[8]
// And you are left with the minimum calculations required to apply a particular rotation Or any other transform.

Matrix3.prototype.rotateX = function(angle, result = new Matrix3()) {
    const r = result.data;
    const d = this.data;
    const c = Math.cos(angle);
    const s = Math.sin(angle);
    const ns = -s;
    r[0] = d[0];
    r[1] = d[1] * c + d[2] * ns;
    r[2] = d[1] * s + d[2] * c;
    r[3] = d[3];
    r[4] = d[4] * c + d[5] * ns;
    r[5] = d[4] * s + d[5] * c;
    r[6] = d[6];
    r[7] = d[7] * c + d[8] * ns;
    r[8] = d[7] * s + d[8] * c;     
    return result;
}
Matrix3.prototype.rotateY = function(angle, result = new Matrix3()) {
    const r = result.data;
    const d = this.data;
    const c = Math.cos(angle);
    const s = Math.sin(angle);
    const ns = -s;
    r[0] = d[0] * c + d[2] * ns;
    r[1] = d[1];
    r[2] = d[0] * s + d[2] * c;
 
    r[3] = d[3] * c + d[5] * ns;
    r[4] = d[4];
    r[5] = d[3] * s + d[5] * c;
 
    r[6] = d[6] * c + d[8] * ns;
    r[7] = d[7];
    r[8] = d[6] * s + d[8] * c;     
    return result;
}
Matrix3.prototype.rotateZ = function(angle, result = new Matrix3()) {
    const r = result.data;
    const d = this.data;
    const c = Math.cos(angle);
    const s = Math.sin(angle);
    const ns = -s;
    r[0] = d[0] * c + d[1] * ns;
    r[1] = d[0] * s + d[1] * c;
    r[2] = d[2];
 
    r[3] = d[3] * c + d[4] * ns;
    r[4] = d[3] * s + d[4] * c;
    r[5] = d[5];
 
    r[6] = d[6] * c + d[7] * ns;
    r[7] = d[6] * s + d[7] * c;     
    r[8] = d[8];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Blindman67,I'm implemented all of your ideas and it looks pretty good so far: https://yovchenko.github.io/sphere/
Only creating a rotation matrix by directly multiplying a matrix was too difficult for me.Could you help me one more time,please?Show an example of the code

Comment: @WladimirYovchenko I have added the 3 rotation matrix multiplications and some info on how to optimise the multiplication (please note that it was typed by hand and not run, there may be some typos in the code)